# Как использовать один adapter для нескольких фрагментов?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, adapter

Имеется несколько фрагментов. В каждом из фрагментов есть `RecyclerView` со своим `adapter`'ом.
На момент создания 3-го адаптера понял, что они в принципе схожи по своей структуре, ну что разве за исключением массивов в которых я храню текст и картинки.
Ну и собственно меня натолкнуло на мысль, как возможно, а главное стоит ли использовать для всех моих фрагментов?
На данный момент код одного из моих адаптеров следующий:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String[] titles = {"Chapter One",
            "Chapter Two",
            "Chapter Three",
            "Chapter Four",
            "Chapter Five",
            "Chapter Six",
            "Chapter Seven",
            "Chapter Eight"};

    private String[] details = {"Item one details",
            "Item two details", "Item three details",
            "Item four details", "Item file details",
            "Item six details", "Item seven details",
            "Item eight details"};

    private int[] images = { R.drawable.android_image_1,
            R.drawable.android_image_2,
            R.drawable.android_image_3,
            R.drawable.android_image_4,
            R.drawable.android_image_5,
            R.drawable.android_image_6,
            R.drawable.android_image_7,
            R.drawable.android_image_8 };

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public int currentItem;
        public ImageView itemImage;
        public TextView itemTitle;
        public TextView itemDetail;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            itemTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            itemDetail =
                    (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    Snackbar.make(v, "Click detected on item " + position,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titles[i]);
        viewHolder.itemDetail.setText(details[i]);
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: у себя в проекте использую либу https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, можно определить адаптер следующим образом:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String[] titles;

    private String[] details;

    private int[] images;

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public int currentItem;
        public ImageView itemImage;
        public TextView itemTitle;
        public TextView itemDetail;

        public CardAdapter(String[] titles, String[] details, int[] images) {
            this.titles = new String[titles.length];
            System.arraycopy(titles, 0, this.titles, 0, titles.length);

            this.details = new String[details.length];
            System.arraycopy(details, 0, this.details, 0, details.length);

            this.images = new int[images.length];
            System.arraycopy(images, 0, this.images, 0, images.length);
        }

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            itemTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            itemDetail =
                    (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    Snackbar.make(v, "Click detected on item " + position,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titles[i]);
        viewHolder.itemDetail.setText(details[i]);
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }
}
```

И при создании адаптера использовать следующий конструктор:

```
public CardAdapter(String[] titles, String[] details, int[] images)
```

Куда передавать Ваши конкретные для каждого адаптера `titles`, `details` и `images`.

---

А вообще, **если** у Вас **элементы списка постоянны**, то правильнее будем воспользоваться наследованием, **чем выносить инициализацию** этих статичных элементов **куда-либо за пределы адаптера**.

---

А самый правильный способ, наверное, заключается в реализации в адаптере методов, которые будут инициализировать массивы. Добавляете в адаптер конструктор, который будет принимать некоторое значение – тип адаптера, и, в зависимости от этого типа из конструктора будет вызываться соответствующий метод для инициализации массивов.

Пример:

```
public CardAdapter(int type) {
    switch (type) {
        case 0:
            // вызов метода для инициализации массивов одними значениями
            break;
        case 1:
            // вызов метода для инициализации массивов другими значениями
            break;
        case 2:
            // вызов метода для инициализации массивов третьими значениями
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вот с дополнением не совсем понятно. Ну я собираюсь добавлять в каждый из списков на данный момент 10 элементов, в будущем может добавлю еще парочку, так что можно считать постоянными.
Можете пожалуйста пояснить как именно воспользоваться в данной ситуации наследованием?

Comment: @VadimMorozov, Суть даже не в наследовании, а в том, что если элементы списка постоянны, то не стоит выносить их инициализацию за пределы адаптера. Есть несколько способов добиться этого. Читайте самое последнее дополнение, оно, по моему мнению, самое верное.

Comment: в коде, "правильный способ" к сожалению не описан.
В конструктор если верно понимаю, заносим наши одинаковые параметры для каждого элемента, а вот с вызовом методов для инициализации массивов не совсем уловил(

Comment: @VadimMorozov, Добавил пример.

Answer (score 3):

Во первых не используй массивы. Используй List!
Во вторых не используй несколько массивов. Используй один `List<YourItem>`.

```
public class YourItem{
    private String title;

    private String detail;

    private int image;

    ...
}
```

и в адатер передавай список этих итемов.
и тогда сможешь один адаптер для нескольких юзать.