# Обращение к элементу через RecyclerView

Tags: android

Есть список из изображений (`RecyclerView`). Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на определенное изображение приложение переходило на ОПРЕДЕЛЕННОЕ активити? Каждому изображению своё активити, а не всем изображениям одно.
Код адаптера:

```
public class PAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PAdapter.Holder>{

private List<PAlert> expenseList;
private Context context;

public PAdapter(List<PAlert> expenseList){
    this.expenseList = expenseList;
}

@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.people_alert,parent,false);

    return new Holder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, final int position) {
    PAlert expense= expenseList.get(position);
    holder.img.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.blackwidow));
    holder.name.setText(expense.alert_name);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return expenseList.size();
}

class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView img;
    public TextView name;


    public Holder (View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alert_img);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alert_name);
    }
}
```

}

Лист

```
public class People extends AppCompatActivity {
private Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_people);
    initRecyclerView();
}
private void initRecyclerView()
{
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.people_alert);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    PAdapter alertAdapter = new PAdapter(getAlerts());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(alertAdapter);
}
private List<PAlert> getAlerts(){
    List<PAlert> expenses = new ArrayList<>();
    expenses.add(new PAlert(R.drawable.blackwidow, "2 дня назад"));
    expenses.add(new PAlert(R.drawable.also, "2 дня назад"));
    expenses.add(new PAlert(R.drawable.iron_man, "2 дня назад"));
    expenses.add(new PAlert(R.drawable.dontremember, "2 дня назад"));
    expenses.add(new PAlert(R.drawable.halk, "2 дня назад"));
    expenses.add(new PAlert(R.drawable.nigga, "2 дня назад"));
    return expenses;
}
```

Comment: Покажите код адаптера `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @post_zeew добавила

Comment: @A.Whole не могли бы подсказать, как у Вас реализован private List<PAlert> expenseList; я так понимаю вы из него берете картинки/текст для recycler'a который отображаете.
Если возможно дополнить вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579665/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-adapter-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @VadimMorozov добавила

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дополните метод `onBindViewHolder()` следующим кодом:

```
    final Context context = holder.img.getContext();
    holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(context, ActivityZero.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(context, ActivityOne.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    intent = new Intent(context, ActivityTwo.class);
                    break;
            }
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Так будет прослушиваться клик только по картинке. Если хотите, чтобы прослушивался клик по всему item из `RecyclerView`, то замените `holder.img` на `((View)holder.img.getParent())`.

Comment: Хорошо, а если мы используем один адаптер для нескольких recyclerView? то как тогда быть с переходом к активностям?

Comment: @VadimMorozov Можно в качестве параметра конструктора адаптера передать ArrayList<Class<?>>, который заполнить подходящими значениями: list.add(ActivityOne.class), ...(как в принятом ответе вопроса http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893908/how-to-create-an-arraylist-of-classes)